# How create account with other existing account settings

Tags: desktop, settings

I configure my account in Elementary OS, and I want duplicate this account. I just want to gain all setting, exactly configure my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your account is Alice, and your duplicated account should be Bob. Sorry, my screenshots are in German, but I will explain it in English.

1. Create the second account Bob by using System preferences (`switchboard`), `user` plug. Add name Bob, the password and so on. After that, login with this user to create the home folder (will be found in `/home/bob/`).
2. Start `Files` as admin (please be aware that working with root privileges could be dangerous) by typing in terminal: `gksudo pantheon-files`. Please type your password.
3. Find the two home folders of Alice and Bob (`/home/alice/` and `/home/bob/`). Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden files.
4. Copy all folders beginning with `.` from Alice's home folder to Bob's home folder.

Going with this, your accounts now have the same settings, after new login.